# Validating whether text lies in a particular range on dynamically created table not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamically created table and onclick of button in a row a modal opens like this:

[image]

If I type anything then it must show alert...

```
<div class="modal fade" id= "{{pl.id}}_1" role="dialog" data-id="{{pl.id}}">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <!-- Modal content-->
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
       <h4 class="modal-title">Do You want to accept <b>{pl.employee.emp_name|title }} </b> leave?</h4>
     </div>
     <form action={% url 'm_manage:accept' %}  method="POST">
     {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="modal-body">
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="email" class="email" > Notify Via Email<br></p>
         <p><label for="message">Message </label>
         <textarea rows="3" name="message"  class="form-control input-md message"></textarea></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success accept" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="checkLength()">Accept</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     </div>
     </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


function checkLength(){
var textbox = document.getElementsByClassName("message");
console.log(textbox.value);
if(textbox.value.length <= 100 && textbox.value.length >= 0){
}
else{
    alert("Make sure the input is between 1-100 characters long")
    }
}
```

console.log is printing value as undefined...I am using get elements by classname as their is duplicacy if i use Id..What is the actual problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this JS code:

```
function checkLength(that){
  var textbox = that.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("message")[0];
  console.log(textbox.value);
  if(textbox.value.length <= 100 && textbox.value.length >= 0){
  }
  else{
    alert("Make sure the input is between 1-100 characters long")
  }
}
```

And in your HTML pass the parameter `this` in function `checkLength(this)`.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success accept" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="checkLength(this)">Accept</button>
```

Comment: Thank You So much.....Its working.......I am a beginner...So please can you tell me actually where I went wrong...?and the use of parentNode twice and how is it giving the values of 2nd nd 3rd element though you gave index as 0.

Comment: @divya  1. `getElementsByClassName` returns array for that you have to use the index as in other answer they are using. But you are creating many textarea dynamically so `[0]` will always select first element.

Comment: `parentNode` is used to select the parent of the `object.checklength` is called by a button. first `parentNode` will select the "modal-footer" and second `parentNode`will select the `form` so now you have a specific part of code. in which you have to find the textarea. not inside the whole document.

Comment: When you will click on 3rd button it will find the textarea within that modal not in the whole document. so it will be fine. 0 is given just because `getElementsByClassName` will return the array. and your element will be at 0 index always because there will be only one element.

Comment: Yaa for sure....You are using this and that for current object or any other importance?suggest some good ways to improve js..

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` gets all elements having a particular class. To get access to `message` textarea, you need to change the following code:

`var textbox = document.getElementsByClassName("message");`

to

`var textbox = document.getElementsByClassName("message")[0];`

Comment: @divya What do you see for `console.log(textbox.value)`?

Comment: Its showing the value for textbox[0].value for the 1st element and null for the rest and its also printing in console : Cannot read property 'length' of undefined  at checkLength()..Therfore the alert is not popping up...

Answer (score 0):

getElement**s**ByClassName returns not just one element, but an array-like of elements. Try doing textbox[0].value.